# Dramatic increase in server response time, is this related to the size of database/tables?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-performance

We have a MySQL database ~2 GB in size. Recently, our server average response time has been dramatically increased. Each of our main tables are ~180 MB in size. Is there a relationship between the increase in the server response time and database size? What would be the largest table size that can be handled by a MySQL database without having a serious decline in database/server performance?

[image: server response time]

Comment: Response time depends on your (Server Resources, Server Configurations, Database Structure, Connection Speed if calling remote server, And the SQL Query you're running), You can enable slow queries log & check what's the longest running query so you can fix that.

Comment: @ahmad, thanks for your response, could please provide me more information about the slow query log?

Comment: Here's the explanation from mysql website: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html basically when you enable it, any query that takes longer than x amount of time will be logged, you can examine these queries manually & adjust indexes ..etc for tables to get better over-all performance.

Comment: The first cut is always the deepest ...